# Why the dtype parameter of pd.Series cannot be used to convert integer strings to ints, but can convert to floats?

Tags: pandas

Can someone please explain the following ValueError for me:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'1.3.5'
>>> pd.Series(['1', '2'], dtype='float64')
0    1.0
1    2.0
dtype: float64
>>> pd.Series(['1', '2'], dtype='int64')
C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py:2446: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  return bool(asarray(a1 == a2).all())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3444, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-20-171b1b2dceb0>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.Series(['1', '2'], dtype='int64')
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 439, in __init__
    data = sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy)
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 569, in sanitize_array
    subarr = _try_cast(data, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 754, in _try_cast
    subarr = maybe_cast_to_integer_array(arr, dtype)
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 2094, in maybe_cast_to_integer_array
    raise ValueError(f"values cannot be losslessly cast to {dtype}")
ValueError: values cannot be losslessly cast to int64
```

Comment: @QuangHoang even `dtype=int` raises `ValueError: values cannot be losslessly cast to int32` for me.

Comment: On my system, it throws the same warning but no error. Must be a numpy thing. Strangely, re-run the command again did not raise any error/warning. That's why I thought `dtype=int` works.

Comment: Good point, I'll update `numpy` and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately upgrading numpy to v1.21.4 did not solve the issue.

Comment: I've opened an issue at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44923 .